BigCommerce - How to Disable/Bypass reCAPTCHA for automation on testing environment?
I'm currently working on automating end-to-end (E2E) tests for a BigCommerce - web application that uses Google reCAPTCHA.
Here are the specifics of my setup:
Web application: based on BigCommerce
reCAPTCHA Version: Seems v2
What I Need Help With:
Disabling reCAPTCHA: Is there a way to programmatically disable reCAPTCHA during tests? For example, a specific flag or configuration setting?
Bypassing reCAPTCHA: If disabling is not possible, how can I reliably bypass it in an automated test scenario?

Please share the site and your code attempt so far as a [mcve]. No, Playwright doesn't have a setting that lets you bypass captcha. Captcha is designed specifically not to be bypassed. You could experiment with something like https://github.com/xrip/playwright-recaptcha-solver but it'd probably be better to get a testing build of your site without the captchas.

Bypassing reCAPTCHA is against the terms of service for many websites, as it is a security measure designed to prevent automated access.
It's important to respect the terms of service and privacy policies of websites you interact with.
However, if you are testing your own/your company site, you need to contact the development/security team and find a solution that acceptable on them.
Some of the possible ways:

disabling reCapcha on testing environment
disabling reCapcha for dedicated test users
some capcha providers has a workaround for testing environments

